# Using cpp tflite API in coral dev-board

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tpu, google-coral

I am trying to use the cpp tflite API to query a model on the dev-board. The code was tested with a usb-stick and works ok , however , on the dev-board I get an error on this line:

```
model_interpreter_ = coral::BuildEdgeTpuInterpreter(*model_, this->edgetpu_context_.get());
```

this is the error:

```
INFO: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
ERROR: Failed to retrieve TPU context.
ERROR: Node number 0 (edgetpu-custom-op) failed to prepare.
```

Same model works OK using python API.

Is there support for tflite cpp API on the dev-board?

On the dev-board I have the latest version(12-1)
and this is what I did to build tflite lib:

1. Build tflite locally for arm64 (using the build generic script, not like described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64)) I used branch v.2.0.
   *reason is lack of virtual memory and disk space to build on the dev-board.
2. On the dev board  installed flatbuffer.

**Edit:**
I was able to build tflite from tensorflow branch v2.0 on the dev-board, updated to link against the locally built lib , still get the same error...

**EDIT 2:**
I was able to reproduce the same beaviour with tflite compiled form tf-r1.15. Also I tried adding a print of num of available tpus as was suggested by @Nam Vu. so here is a code snippet:

```
cout << "check num available tpus\n";
    cout << available_tpus.size() << "\n";
    cout << "get edge session\n";
    this->edgetpu_context_ = edgetpu::EdgeTpuManager::GetSingleton()->OpenDevice();
    cout << "check num available tpus again:\n";
    cout << available_tpus.size() << "\n";
    cout << "get model buffer\n";
    this->model_ = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(model_path.c_str());
    cout << "build model interpeter\n";
    this->model_interpreter_ = coral::BuildEdgeTpuInterpreter(*model_, this->edgetpu_context_.get());
```

resulting in:

```
Hello
check num available tpus
3689348814741910324
get edge session
check num available tpus again:
3689348814741910324
get model buffer
build model interpeter
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if it's somehow not detecting the tpu, can you try this:

```
const auto& available_tpus = edgetpu::EdgeTpuManager::GetSingleton()->EnumerateEdgeTpu();
cout << available_tpus.size() << "\n"; // hopefully we'll see 1 here
```

Then create the context:

```
std::shared_ptr<edgetpu::EdgeTpuContext> edgetpu_context =
          edgetpu::EdgeTpuManager::GetSingleton()->OpenDevice(
            available_tpus[0].type, available_tpus[0].path);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I get an undefined number as num cpus. will update in the question

Comment: Hi Omer, it's a littte harder to diagnose without know more about how you built the project. Can you try checking out and build the static tensorflow lib from this commit: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/blob/master/WORKSPACE#L5

Comment: Or you could try cross compiling it from there with this (you'll need docker on your host machine and output will be in the 'out' dir:
`$ make DOCKER_IMAGE=debian:strech DOCKER_CPUS="aarch64" docker-build`